# How to get a value from a simple_form in the same view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to get a value from a `f.association` in a form of `simple_form`. This gets its value from a controller and transfers all the rooms, I need the value to load a bootstrap 5 modal that I need to reload the information of the selected room.

The modal works, but I need to occupy the `set_parms`, to get the data.

Can you give me ideas or how to do it?

This is my existing code:

Form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@reservation, @item_reservation] do |f| %>
  <%= f.association :room, collection: @room.map{|r| [r.name, r.id]} %>
  <%= f.submit "Add" %>
  <button type="button" class="btn " data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
  <%= link_to "Back", client_reservations_path(@reservation.client_id) %>
<% end %>
```

View

```
<h1>ItemReservations#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/item_reservations/new.html.erb</p>
<td><%= link_to "Follow", new_reservation_user_reservation_path(@reservation)%> </td>

<%=render "form", item_reservation: @item_reservation %>
<%= link_to "Back", client_reservations_path(@reservation.client_id) %>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>
<h2>Rooms</h2>
<div class="text-end">
  <small><%= @message %></small>
</div>
<br/>
<table id="Room_select" class="table table-striped table-sm">
  
  <head>
```

Comment: as i understand, when user select a room and submit the form you want to open a modal with the data of the selected room right?

Comment: yes that is in short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption:

-- you have done:

1. Page loads with reservation form
2. User selects a room from the select field
3. User clicks "Launch demo modal" button

-- you need to do:

4. Room data should be added to the modal
5. The modal should open

If this is all correct, you have a few options:

1. Rails 7 comes with [Hotwire](https://hotwired.dev/) for situations just like this
2. Use Rails [AJAX and UJS](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/03/rails-ajax/) for older versions of Rails, or if you don't want to learn Turbo and Hotwire.
3. Use [Javascript and AJAX](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ajax/index.htm) without Rails

---

With any of these options, you are essentially going to:

1. Get the currently selected option from the select field
2. Send that option to a custom Rails controller (e.g. `RoomsController#modal_show`) remotely (using AJAX or Turbo (Hotwire))
3. The controller will load the room data and send back some Javascript to execute (or HTML to render in the case of Hotwire)
4. The returned Javascript will put the room data into the modal and trigger the modal to open

Comment: If that is true, you hit it, the summary you gave me of what you suppose is 100% real, and I only need point 4, I am doing it with rails 6. For what you tell me, I must make a new function in the controller thank you for your reply